# ORMLite jar shared between Android and Java projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ormlite

I'm facing a lot of problem with ORMLite. I have and Android project which has the `ormlite-android-4.47.jar`into libs folder and I want to place the `ormlite-core-4.47.jar` into the libs folder situated in a Java project. I want to do this because I have classes that have to be used in different projects and I don't want redundant code.

However the two projects are related by `Configure Build Path` (I'm using Eclipse as IDE) and when I try to launch the Android project, the classes that have ORMLite annotation inside them give me a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Note that if I put the classes annotated with ORMLite annotation into the Android project everything works.

Could someone help me?

Comment: This isn't a problem with ORMLite.  It's a problem that I also have with Android projects depending on other projects.  As far as I know it doesn't work well.

Comment: It doesn't work simply. Bad luck for me too :-(